# Self signed certificate over different machines - Invalid keystore format error

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, self-signed, jks

I have created a Restful service and as a part of security, I have created a self signed certificate for the requests to be sent securely.

I have used the `keytool` command to create this self signed certificate.

Now it is working fine, but the problem is when I run the same project on a different machine by copying the .jks I created in the other machine, I get "Invalid keystore format" exception.

If I again create a new .jks file in the second machine using the `keytool` command, then my project is running fine. But if I copy the same .jks I'm getting this error.

Please help me understand this, I'm new to creating and adding certificates and keystores :)

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You've copied the file incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't get it.. I just right click copy and put in my flash drive.

Comment: Compare the files using a checksum command like `md5sum` on each machine.

Comment: Ok I used WinMD5 tool to determine the checksum value in both the machines and both are equal.
dc29d075be0f9cc2deaffd9d50625459